# Set DNS Server on Zone using C#

Tags: visual-studio, windows-dns

I would like to set the primary ns server on a domain I am creating on Windows Server programmatically:

```
ManagementBaseObject outParams = zoneObj.InvokeMethod("CreateZone", inParams, null);ManagementClass zoneObj = new ManagementClass(session, new ManagementPath("MicrosoftDNS_Zone"), null);
ManagementBaseObject inParams = zoneObj.GetMethodParameters("CreateZone");
inParams["ZoneName"] = "mydomain.com";
inParams["ZoneType"] = 0;
inParams["DNSServer"] = "ns1.myserver.com"; //--- I am getting an error here!
ManagementBaseObject outParams = zoneObj.InvokeMethod("CreateZone", inParams, null);
```

I am failing to set this but I have tried:
dnsserver,
nsserver,
dnsname,

All cant work.

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/a/19663743 help?

Comment: Thanks, I saw this one. It is about integrating the zone to AD. I want to set the NS server to a different one than localhost